# How to use IgnoreMember to ignore a child property of a json object in VerifyTests

Tags: c#, .net, verify, verify-tests

I have a json string and I want the Verify library to ignore the child property **bbb**.

I can ignore the whole **aaa** property by
`await VerifyJson(result).IgnoreMember("aaa");`

But I do not know how to ignore the child property **bbb**.

I tried `await VerifyJson(result).IgnoreMember("aaa.bbb")` but it doesn't work

```
{
   "aaa": {
     "bbb": "1111"
   }
}
```